# Entity Framework Database First generation crash MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, entity-framework, nuget

I am trying to generate code from an existing MySql database. 
I'm following this guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj206878(v=vs.113).aspx

When I select the database from my data connections the wizard just disappears. I have read something about this being caused by MySql NuGet packages version mismatch, but I seem to have the correct versions. These are my installed NuGet packages.

[image]

Also, I see a lot of mention of "Connector/Net" can someone tell me what that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wizard closing is a known bug in MySQL Connector/NET:

- [Bug 89338](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89338) for 6.10.5
- [Bug 91195](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91195) for 8.0.11

You will need to wait for Oracle to fix this bug and ship an update. Some people have reported being able to work around the problem by following [these instructions](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,667307,667319#msg-667319).

"Connector/NET" is just another name for the `MySql.Data` library plus the additional Visual Studio addins; for example, it's used in [this documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/).

Comment: First of all, thanks! I'll try the guide tomorrow. Does downgrading also not work? I have tried it with Mysql.data 6.9.12, but without success.

Comment: It's possible the bug may be in MySQL for Visual Studio (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/1.2.html), not in the MySql.Data library; if that's true (I'm not sure if it is or not) installing a different version from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/1.2.html may help.