# Making an Entity Framework 6 Model in Visual Studio closes Wizard and disconnects MYSQL Connection Database

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Im trying to add a ADO.Net Entity  Data Model using Entity Framework 6  to a  Net.Framework Class Library, but when I get to  Step 3, when you choose the Framework version it immediately closes the wizard and my connection to my MYSQL Database [This is what it shows before it closes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3jV8.png)automatically disconnects.

My App.Config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
        connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;database=mycontext;uid=root;password=********"/>
</connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
          type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"/>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"
          type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.12.0" newVersion="8.0.12.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Protobuf" publicKeyToken="a7d26565bac4d604" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.6.1.0" newVersion="3.6.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I have installed Entity Framework 6.20, Mysql.Data 8.0.12, MySql.Data.Entity 6.10.8, Google.Protobuf 3.6.1 installed in the class library with NuGet and added as references. And I have reinstalled, updated, used the MYSQL Installer them with no luck.

I have an Net.Core Web API Application as the first project as well, but I know that Net.core does not support Framework 6, only Entity core, so you have to add the net.framework class library and add those references in the libary.

Just to note I'm **not** (See Picture) having the same error as "An entity Framework database provider could not be found" I'm not having that error, the framework version is automatically selected, but it closes. Thank you.

**EDIT**

For those who come across this problem I have a workaround, I had to uninstall the Net Connector from the Installer and download Net Connector 6.10.8 separately and things should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Database First generation crash MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51525301/entity-framework-database-first-generation-crash-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in MySQL VS integration: [bug 91195](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91195).

Some other users have posted workarounds that they've found at that link. You may need to wait for Oracle to release a VS addin that doesn't crash.

Comment: Would I have to downgrade other mySQL Components such as the Server,workbench etc?

Comment: No, those are independent of the VS addin.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your workaround but it just gave me some more errors and other issues, know any alternative? I believe it's an issue with the Visual Studio Plugin rather than the connector.  I have tried different versions of the MySQL. connector  but to no avail. It's a pretty big big bug too.

Comment: Yes, it's a problem in the VS addin; it has nothing to do with the ADO.NET connector. (Sometimes the Connector/NET installer bundles the VS addin, but that's the only connection between the two.)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work with the versions: connector 6.10.8  and  MySQL for VS 1.2.8