# Mysql Entity Framework Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to use Mysql for my database and using ASP.NET to develop my web apps so far. But when I try to add ADO.NET Entity Model from my mysql database, it always give me nothing. The Wizard always closed before I select the tables.

Here my packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.3.7" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Google.Protobuf" version="3.5.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="3.3.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" version="2.5.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept" version="2.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector" version="2.5.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector" version="2.5.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" version="2.5.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer" version="2.5.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel" version="2.5.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.8.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="MySql.Data" version="8.0.12" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="MySql.Data.Entity" version="6.10.8" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="4.4.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

And this is an error that I got

[image]

I know it's because I'm not using latest EF version.

After I update my EF version to the latest, this is what i got
[image]

Entity Data Model Wizard window suddenly closed before I able to click next or choose any table. Fortunately I able to capture this image a few milliseconds before it's closed

Comment: got some reading homework for you: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

Comment: and a tutorial: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/mysqlentityframeworkcodefirst-for-net-developers

Comment: for the record, I'm not using Code First from database but EF Designer from database. 
Anw, I tried the configuration already but my problem persist

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making an Entity Framework 6 Model in Visual Studio closes Wizard and disconnects MYSQL Connection Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52058979/making-an-entity-framework-6-model-in-visual-studio-closes-wizard-and-disconnect)

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52060503. This is a bug in the MySQL VS addin; you will need to wait for Oracle to release a fix.